# Variable selection with a separate subset

Tags: logistic, cross-validation, modeling, bootstrap, lasso

I have a small sample, 199 to be exact (clinical data), is it necessary to perform Lasso variable selection on a subset which is different from training set?

Comment: How many predictor variables do you have? That is important information!

Comment: 71 variables; unbalanced 2 groups (died 179, survivors 20)

Answer (score 0):

You could try lasso. Using a separate validation set with so few observations is probably inadvisable. Use tenfold cross validation and maybe the bootstrap. Cross fingers!

Comment: Cheers, will try tht!